# How can I find maven property names for libraries?

Tags: maven

I have these properties defined in my pom.xml -

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <powermock.version>1.6.2</powermock.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.artifact.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.artifact.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.6</logback.version>
</properties>
```

I am trying to understand where these properties names are defined - powermock.version, logback.version? How do I know that the version of the ch.qos.logback.core library is determined by the logback.version property? I looked for this information quite a bit and found there are many well known properties like maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target but nothing that explains the version ones.

Comment: can you look at the complete pom, you would find there usage within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`Maven Properties`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) are
>   value placeholder, like properties in Ant. Their values are accessible
>   anywhere within a POM by using the notation ${X}, where X is the
>   property.

Your current usage is the 5th style mentioned in the above link

> x: Set within a  element in the POM. The value of
>   value may be used as
>   ${someVar}.

Its effectiveness comes into act when you want to use the same variable for multiple artifacts that might or might not be a part of same groupId.

For example -

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

You can further define a dependency using the same property as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version> <!-- version would be fetched from properties-->
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version> <!-- version would be fetched from properties-->
</dependency>
```

which is similar to

```
<version>3.1.2</version>
```

ensuring that both artifacts are on the same version as well.

Comment: I found where the property is defined and used...I will post the details as an answer because comments are hard to put code into...unless there is another way...I am relatively new to posting on SO.

Comment: @rmulay - if the problem is solved do mark this as an answer. The exact presence of the properties in your code might not be something that would help others to learn(IMO, would suggest you can still update the same in the question). Though if you still find an answer worth sharing that someone else can learn from, please don't hesitate. Being new to the community I expect you must have gone through http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Cheers.

Comment: Oops...just saw your comment after I posted another answer to the question! I accepted your answer. I thought my answer can help others who use spring.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @nullpointer, I did some digging and here is what I found. I wanted to this as a comment but I found it hard to format this in a comment. I hope it is ok to post this as an answer. I am relatively new to posting on SO...so let me know if this should be done differently. I will accept @nullpointer answer even though this is an answer too.

My 'super' pom includes this -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

spring-boot-starter-parent pom contains this -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../../spring-boot-dependencies</relativePath>
</parent>
```

spring-boot-dependencies pom contains -

```
<properties>
...
    <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
...
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```